# C++ Problem: 'break' within nested for loops not working as expected?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program to find a specific 4 digit number with the following conditions:

- All four digits are different.
- The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place.
- The number is odd.
- The sum of the digits is 27.

I'm struggling to write this program. I tried nested for loops iterating each digit until the conditions are met (when a break terminates the loops), as below:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;
int d = 1;

for (a = 1; a < 9; a++) {
    for (b = 1; b < 9; b++) {
        for (c = 1; c < 9; c++) {
            for (d = 1; d < 9; d++) {

                if (a + b + c + d == 27 && a == 3 * c && a != b && a != c
                && a != d && b!= c && b != d && c != d && d % 2 != 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the digits a, b, c, d to provide me with the number to fulfil all conditions in the if statement above and thus to break. Instead, abcd is always 9999. Why is this happening? How am I misusing break?

Comment: Your conditions are wrong, you are never building a number out of the 4 digits.

Comment: create a function containing this `for` loops and use `return` instead of `break`

Comment: I suggest breaking up your if statement into nested if statements: `if(condition1){ if(condition2){ if(condition3){. . .} } }` so that debugging is easier.

Comment: you are only considering 8 out of 10 possible digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break` will only break out of the inner most loop.  So when you hit your condition, you just go into the next iteration of the `c` value.

Comment: Got it thanks very much. I will place it in the outer most loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int findNum();

int main()
{
    int num;
    num = findNum();
    printf("%d is the required number.\n\n",num);
    return 0;
}

int findNum()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    for (a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
            {
                for (d = 0; d <= 9; d++)
                {
                    if (a+b+c+d==27 && a==(3*c) && a!=b && a!=c && a!=d && b!=c && b!=d && c!=d && (d%2)!=0)
                    {
                        return (1000*a)+(100*b)+(10*c)+d;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Break only breaks the inner loop if you want to come out of all the loops either you can use return or use a variable say flag

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;
int d = 1;
int flag=0;
for (a = 1; a < 9; a++) {
    for (b = 1; b < 9; b++) {
        for (c = 1; c < 9; c++) {
            for (d = 1; d < 9; d++) {

if (a + b + c + d == 27 && a == 3 * c && a != b && a != c
&& a != d && b!= c && b != d && c != d && d % 2 != 0) {
flag=1;
                    break;//breaks d loop
}
if(flag==1)
break;//breaks c loop
}
if(flag==1)
break;//breaks b loop
}
if(flag==1)
break;//breaks a loop
}
```

This is a bad practice but will give correct output . I would prefer using return statement or you can use goto statement to jump out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting the calculation into a function and exiting the function when the conditions are met with `return`, and return the value.

**My Suggested Improvements**

- In your original code, you're only testing values from 1 to 8 when 0 through 9 must be tested.
- For `a`, only 3, 6, and 9 must be tested.
- `c` can be derived from `a`, so you can eliminate the for loop testing `c` values.
- Only loop for odd numbers in `d` loop.
- Switch `b` and `d` loop so that code in outer loop runs less times.
- Separate the if statements so that it's easier to read, and you can step through the conditions line-by-line in a debugger, and errors can be specified on which condition produced the error easier.
- `a` will never equal `c`, so no need to check.
- Check `a` and `c` don't equal `d` right inside `d` loop.
- Check `b` doesn't equal other digits before adding digits and checking they equal 27.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int find_number(){
    int a, b, c, d, result;

    for(a = 3; a <= 9; a += 3){ // Only runs 3 times
        c = a/3;
        for(d = 1; d <= 9; d += 2){
            if(a != d){
            if(c != d){
                for(b = 0; b <= 9; b++){
                    if(b != d){
                    if(b != a){
                    if(b != c){
                    if(a + b + c + d == 27){ 
                        result = a*1000 + b*100 + c*10 + d;
                        return result;
                    } // end ifs
                    }
                    }
                    }
                } // end for
            } // end ifs
            }
        } // end for
    } // end for

} // end find_number()

int main()
{
    cout << find_number() << endl;

    return 0;
} // end main()
```

Comment: *"Separate the if statements so that it's easier to read."* Ugh, that's very subjective. (Also the lack of indentation... You even had to put comments on closing braces because of it.)

Comment: You're right, it's subjective, but you can't step through the conditions if they're all on one line (which might be something I should include in the answer... I usually put comments on closed brackets because they're always confusing to me. I think it would look more confusing if they were indented the conventional way. I'll correct it if you think it's bad since you have the seniority on this site.

Comment: No, don't edit it if *you* think your way is better. Even if I have more imaginary internet points, that doesn't necessarily make me right.